# Finding percentages based on column sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

[Link to Image of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nGGC.png)
Good day all,
Please i need help concerning finding percentage on a column. I want to find percentage of each row based on the Base Column in the sample data below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestData](
[Selection] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Criteria] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Heading] [nvarchar](550) NOT NULL,
[Base] [int] NULL,
[WhatImGetting] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
[WhatIWant] [numeric](5, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base],    [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'All', N'All', N'', 5, CAST(100 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(100 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base], [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'Gender', N'Male', N'', 5, CAST(100 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(100 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base], [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'Location', N'Abuja', N'', 2, CAST(40 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(40 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base], [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'Location', N'Kano', N'', 3, CAST(60 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(60 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base], [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'MaritalStatus', N'Married', N'', 2, CAST(40 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(40 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base], [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'MaritalStatus', N'Single', N'', 3, CAST(60 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(60 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base], [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'Question1', N'3yrs – 4 yrs.', N'Q1. How long has this business existed?', 3, CAST(60 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(75 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([Selection], [Criteria], [Heading], [Base], [WhatImGetting], [WhatIWant]) VALUES (N'Question1', N'16yrs – 20yrs', N'Q1. How long has this business existed?', 1, CAST(20 AS Numeric(5, 0)), CAST(25 AS Numeric(5, 0)))
GO
```

This is my sample code

```
with cte as (
Select 
  Selection,
  Criteria, 
  Heading,
  Base 
from TestData 
)
Select Selection, 
  Criteria, 
  Heading, 
  Base, 
  cast(round(Base * 100.0/Nullif(
               (select 
                 SUM(case when Selection = 'Gender' then Base Else 0 End) 
               from cte),0),0) as numeric(5,0)) Male  
from cte
```

Others are correct, its when it gets to Question1 under selection that the calculation is wrong, obvious all the calculation is wrong.

Apparently what i want to do is sum the base based on the values in Selection column and use to sum to calculate the percentage
e.g For Question1 which sum is 4, the percentage will be Base * 100/4
which will give me a 25% and a 75%

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Desired results would really help.  I can't visualize what results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please how do i attach an image to show what i want

Comment: . . You can add a text table.  The formatting is basically to put four spaces at the beginning of each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you have `sum` on `base` column when selection is `gender` which will be equal to 5.

```
SUM(case when Selection = 'Gender' then Base Else 0 End
```

Now when you calculate percentage for "question 1 - 3yrs – 4 yrs" whose base is 3,  it will come to 60% and not 75% as you expected. `(3*100)/5`

You suppose to `SUM` by grouping the selection and use it as total to calculate percentage for each row within the group. 
I have modified your query like below, which should work as per expectation in your question

```
with cte as (
Select 
  Selection,
  SUM(BASE) as SelSum -- Sum for each selection group
from TestData 
group by selection
)
Select t.Selection, 
  Criteria, 
  Heading, 
  Base, 
  cast(round(Base * 100.0/Nullif(c.SelSum,0),0) as numeric(5,0)) Male  
from TestData t
inner join cte c on t.selection = c.selection
```

**[Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a3d3/4)**

```
Selection       Criteria        Heading                                 Base Male
All             All                                                     5       100
Gender          Male                                                    5       100
Location        Abuja                                                   2       40
Location        Kano                                                    3       60
MaritalStatus   Married                                                 2       40
MaritalStatus   Single                                                  3       60
Question1       3yrs – 4 yrs.   Q1. How long has this business existed? 3       75
Question1       16yrs – 20yrs   Q1. How long has this business existed? 1       25
```